# Is there any command-line RSS feed file grabber?

Tags: command-line, rss

I'm looking for a command-line program for downloading files from a RSS feed.

When I run this program, it should go to [a RSS webpage](http://www.daveslounge.com/feed/), check whether there are new episodes, and if so, download them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [PodGrab – A Command Line RSS Podcast Downloader Written In Python](http://joshua14.homelinux.org/blog/?p=492). The script can be found [here](http://joshua14.homelinux.org/downloads/PodGrab.py).

> [...] you can add a new feed URL with: -
>
> ```
> PodGrab.py -s http://some.feed.url.xml
> ```
>
> This will store the feed as a subscription and download the latest
>   episode.

Comment: Hey, thank you, but it doesn't seem to work for the URL I provided. I'm getting the error: `Sorry, there was some sort of error: 'Not a valid XML file or URL feed!'`